# How do I create an Alpine local backup overlay (apkovl) with Docker?

Tags: alpine-linux

Alpine's [local backup](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Alpine_local_backup) feature allows an overlay file containing system modifications to be fetched from the network at boot time.

I'd like to make an overlay file on my development system by running Alpine under Docker, the `lbu` utility does not exist in the `alpine:3.12` container image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `lbu` utility is provided by the [`alpine-conf`](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/main/x86_64/alpine-conf) package.